# View/Twig best practice: retrieve sub/child records in controller or view?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, twig

I'm building an application using Twig and Symfony, but this really has to do with general *VC.

When I want to retrieve the child/sub/related records (for example subcategories of the parent categories), should I be:

1. Create a nested array of the data needed in the controller and pass it to the view/Twig.
2. Retrieve the sub records within the view and loop through them there (initially passing in the parent records).

This is provided the sub records can be retrieved with a single method call or access to a single property. In my view anyway, if it requires more than a single method call, it's probably getting too complex for the view.

I realize this is somewhat opinion based, but I'm wondering if there are best practices in general or specifically for Twig or Symfony.

Comment: Try keeping your twig simple. Its supposed to be a template file and not for complex loops. But again like you said this question is opinion based.

Comment: i would go for option 2 ,if you have setup your entities with correct relational annotations then in twig each parent object will also have its associated child entities collection , option 1 will involve more work first creating array (looping all parent and getting its child) and then in twig there will a one more loop to display data parent and child

Comment: I would go for 2 too. The view has to know about the data it's displaying. If it's just a simple loop, then go ahead, don't overcomplicate :-)